# Grouping different addresses according to Areas ,Python

Tags: python, sorting, group-by, pandas, dataframe

I searched for this type of a question on SO but they were somewhat different and could not help me arrive to a conclusion. I have a dataframe with 2 columns , "Area" and "Address" . Out of the 1000 observations , there are 322 unique Area.

My aim is to actually store all the address words that correspond to one Area . I have tried using dict etc but those get too complicated later on. There must be something simple in pandas.
here's a look of my data:

```
Sr.no     Area                Address
  1      vasanth nagar        cant railway station
  2      mahadevapura         akme ballet d1001 outer ring road
  3      whitefield           villa no 106/107 palm medose 
  4      whitefield           fortune hotel,room 4112 opposite sap labs,
  5      vasanth nagar        station cantonment
```

What i want is to group all words that come with whitefield like "villa,no,palm,fortune,hotel,sap labs...etc" and so on. I'd prefer it to be in a list format, but since i'm heading nowhere as of now, any sort of grouping will do which allots all addresses belonging to each unique area to come together. Plz note that I have thousands of observations so it should not be hard-coded.
Finally, what did I do myself?? here is everything:

```
area_ref = data['Area'].sort_index()
area_ref2=set(area_ref)
from collections import defaultdict

grouped = defaultdict(list)
for row in data:
    grouped[row['Area']].append(row['Address'])
        #dint work . error that index should be int , not string.

subset = data[['Area','Address']]
tuples1 = [tuple(x) for x in subset.values]
from collections import defaultdict
res = defaultdict(list)
for v, k in tuples1: res[k].append(v)
di2=[{'type':k, 'items':v} for k,v in res.items()] 
#this last one gave me a really bad dictionary.
```

This should not be complicated . There is some better approach. what could it be?

Comment: can you show the result expected according to input ?

Comment: i want all words related to a specific area be grouped together.. preferably a list @XavierCombelle.

so , 'cant, railway, station ,cantonment...' come under Vasanth nagar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
def collect_to_set(grp):                               # 3
    return set.union(*[set(row.split()) for row in grp['Address']])

data = pd.read_table('data', sep='\s{2,}')             # 1
result = data.groupby(['Area']).apply(collect_to_set)  # 2
print(result)                                          # 4
# Area
# mahadevapura         set([ballet, outer, road, ring, d1001, akme])
# vasanth nagar            set([cant, station, railway, cantonment])
# whitefield       set([hotel,room, sap, fortune, villa, no, oppo...
# dtype: object

print(result.to_dict())                                # 5
# {'vasanth nagar': set(['cant', 'station', 'railway', 'cantonment']),
# 'mahadevapura': set(['ballet', 'outer', 'road', 'ring', 'd1001', 'akme']),
# 'whitefield': set(['hotel,room', 'sap', 'fortune', 'villa', 'no', 'opposite',
# 'palm', 'labs,', '4112', 'medose', '106/107'])}
```

1. I used `read_table` to load your data snippet into a DataFrame.
   Since you already have `data` as a DataFrame, you of course don't
   need this line.
2. This is the main line. It groups `data` by `Area`, and then calls
   the `collect_to_set` function for each group, `grp`.
3. In `collect_to_set`, `grp` is a sub-DataFrame of `data` (with all
   rows having the same `Area`). It returns a `set` of all the words in
   the rows of `grp['Address']`.
4. `result` is a `Series`.
5. If you'd rather have a dict, use `result.to_dict()`.

Comment: and what in case i want the words in 2nd column to be in the form of a list??? thanx a lot.. :)

Comment: If I understand your situation correctly, you should not want a list. The advantage of using a set is that it provides a collection of *unique* words. Moreover, testing membership in a set is `O(1)`, while testing membership in a list is `O(n)`. So, if all you want is to know if certain words are used to describe an area, you should use a `set`. In contrast, a list implies that the *order* of the words matters. If the order does not matter, then a `list` is the wrong choice of data structure. However, if you do want a `list`, then just `return list(set.union(...))` in `collect_to_set`.

Comment: ohhh.. thanks bro. i never knew that. will it be possible for me to use those sets as an input to a function?

Comment: Sure. In Python virtually everything is an object. Any object can be used as input to a function.

Comment: thanx.. you made my day. you could surely join in on the Python chat group some day and help

Answer (score 0):

Make tuple of your entries.As shown below. and run sorted method.

```
d=(('vasanth nagar','cant railway station'),
('mahadevapura','akme ballet d1001 outer ring road'),
('whitefield','villa no 106/107 palm medose '),
('whitefield','fortune hotel,room 4112 opposite sap labs,'),
('vasanth nagar','station cantonment'))

for i in sorted(d):
    print i[0],"     ",i[1]
```

Comment: i have 3 million addresses  to be clear ;) . and im running it on a sample of 1000. i just posted 5 here. as i said in my question, i cant afford a hard-code.